# How do I print my array where it prints out n numbers per line?

Tags: java, sorting, array-algorithms

So I want to print the array full of random integers first before its sorted in rows instead of one huge line so its easier to read

So here the method that controls the output of the entire program

```
//This is the method that controls the output and is what I'm trying to change 
public String toString(){

    String out = "{";
    for(int i = 0; i<a.length-1; i++)
        out+=a[i]+", ";
    if(a.length>0) out+=a[a.length-1]+"}";
```

[The output that I get which I would like to refine and look neater or easier to read than scroll to the right especially for large sets of numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4OPD.png)

Comment: There’s far too much code in your question. The title explains perfectly what you want to do. That should be your question, together with your attempt at a solution

Comment: Please boil down your code to a minimal, complete, and verifiable example which shows your problem. Leave away all unnecessary code. Describe clearly what you expect and what you get instead.

Comment: I just edited it down and I did post a picture of the output lol if that helps